# Am I using the correct model?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, model

I'm new to statistics.

1. What type of model should be used to predict a basketball team's winning percentage? I am currently using a multiple linear model, but the residual vs. predicted plot shows my data points clustered in a circle. I standardized my explanatory variables since they were either percentages or totals.
2. Also, what model should be used for the Pythagorean Expectation formula? I would like to see what that would look like in R.

Thanks!

Comment: I think for starters you may want to consider a logistic or a probit regression where you dependent variable is a basketball team's winning percentage. The Wikipedia articles on both subjects are quite good starting points.

Comment: Are you sure? A win percentage is continuous and can take on more than 2 different values. For both of those models, it suggests usage when dependent variables are binary, e.g. take on a value of 0 or 1.

Comment: Even though win percentage is continous, your dependant variable (did they win or not) is not - it can be either 0 (lose) or 1 (win) (what you do with ties is up to you). Using a logistic regression or linear probability model would probably be your best bet. Then predict from the estimated model.

Comment: @ltronneberg The dV will be a proportion if you have a time series or some other aggregated form of data. In that case you could take the log of the dV and then use a linear model instead of logit or probit.

Comment: @Itronneberg Thanks for that explanation. I will go with logistic.

Comment: @tomka Thanks. That's an interesting thought, but I'm not sure how I would go about doing that with my aggregate data in R.

Comment: @user2205916 : Further to what they guys suggested, you could conceptually even think of your dependant variable as the realization of a R.V. quantifying the probability of "winning all games". Furthermore, if you wish to follow  ltronneberg's suggestion about `win`/`loss` you might want to consider a multinomal logistic regression so you can also account of `tie`. Check the concepts of `logit` and `probit` link functions; I think it will greatly benefit your understanding of the problem. (Sorry for the late reply)

Comment: @usεr11852: Thanks for the advice. I have been reading up on logit link functions and my understanding of the problem has certainly improved. There are no ties in basketball, but thanks for that information.

Comment: @Itronneberg: If you put your comment as an answer I can mark it as such.

Comment: You might find useful references and articles in the Wikipedia article on baseball statistics [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APBRmetrics)

Comment: You would have more information than just win/loose, some scores, so maybe better to model the scores?